# How force remove when post-installation script always fail

Tags: dpkg

I have a custom package installed on my Ubuntu 10.10, and trying to remove it, I got:

```
$ sudo dpkg -r package
sub-process script post-installation installed returne an error state 127
```

(the message returned from the command was translated from portuguese(br).

So, I noted that on the installation script of this package, what it did was create an entry on my startup, create a folder on /opt and create a user.

I removed all it created. But now, I just want to remove it from dpkg list, because I want to make my linux like if I never installed this package.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You may need to manually remove the package using:

```
sudo dpkg --purge --force-all package
```

Replace `package` with the name of the package.

Do note: its recommended to report a bug if the package is not yours or is unknown to you what the script does.

Answer (score 41):

trying to remove xmail with `dpkg --purge --force-all xmail` failed because the pre-removal script was exiting with a failure attempting to stop the xmail daemon. I found the solution here:

- [how to remove a package which post-installation and pre-removal script fails?](https://serverfault.com/questions/179570/how-to-remove-a-package-which-post-installation-and-pre-removal-script-fails)

specifically, I edited `/var/lib/dpkg/info/xmail.prerm` and changed  `|| exit $!` to  `|| true`

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. the other solution doesn't cover all cases, and this provides some help for the remainder.

Comment: If I have to guess, you answer "failed because the pre-removal script", this questions is about the "post-installation" script. You aren't answering the currently asked question.

Comment: I had a problem with the pre-removal script and this helped me.

Comment: As one can expect, if editing `*.prerm` files is too tedious, you can delete them as well - uninstallation process works with them missing

Comment: thanks, didn't know that! that's worth a separate answer, if you want to do so.

Comment: This solved my problem:  `I edited /var/lib/dpkg/info/[packagename].prerm and changed || exit $! to || true`! Thanks