# ubuntu machine had postgresql folder blown away manually - can't install or remove any packages

Tags: command-line, apt, software-center, postgresql

i have a machine where a user deleted their postgresql folder from the command line in an attempt to uninstall postgres. 
now when we try to install any other packages - even unrelated ones - we keep getting error messages about postgresql-common.

I tried to uninstall everything related to postgresql-9.3 and postgresql-9.4  manually via the command line but that's not working.

This is what happens when I try:

```
jj@testdev:~/Documents/svc_core_design/svc_core_git/svc-core-docs/net-svc$ sudo apt-get purge postgresql-client-9.3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'postgresql-client-9.3' is not installed, so not removed
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 postgresql-9.3 : Depends: postgresql-client-9.3 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
jj@testdev:~/Documents/svc_core_design/svc_core_git/svc-core-docs/net-svc$
```

To see what postgresql components he still has I ran the following command:

```
sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall

postgresql-9.3                                  purge
postgresql-client-9.4                           install
postgresql-client-common                        install
postgresql-common                               install
```

I would like to either remove all postgresql related items if possible, or re-install so it's working properly.(don't need both versions if we re-install.  Just 9.4 would be fine.)
Can you tell me how I can do that via command line?

**EDIT 1**

Here are the results from trying to run "sudo apt-get -f install" without any package name:

```
jj@testdev:/var/lib/postgresql$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libjs-underscore linux-image-3.16.0-25-generic linux-image-3.16.0-33-generic linux-image-extra-3.16.0-25-generic linux-image-extra-3.16.0-33-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up postgresql-common (166.pgdg14.10+1) ...
insserv: warning: script 'mongod' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `mongod'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `mongod'
 * Starting PostgreSQL 9.3 database server                                                                                                                                                                                                 * Error: /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main is not accessible or does not exist
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   [fail]
 * Starting PostgreSQL 9.4 database server                                                                                                                                                                                                 * Error: /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main is not accessible or does not exist
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   [fail]
invoke-rc.d: initscript postgresql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package postgresql-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 postgresql-common
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
jj@testdev:/var/lib/postgresql$ sudo
```

I've also made sure that the owner on the /var/lib/postgresql folder is postgres, in case that helps. 
Perhaps I should manually create the folder structure it's complaining about?

```
  /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main
```

Any other suggestions?

**EDIT 2**

I installed aptitude and tried to purge postgresql 9.3 and 9.4 
It fails with:

```
jj@testdev:/var/lib/postgresql$ sudo aptitude purge postgresql-9.3
The following packages will be REMOVED:  
  postgresql-9.3{p} 
The following partially installed packages will be configured:
  postgresql-common 
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 17.6 MB will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] Y
(Reading database ... 339475 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing postgresql-9.3 (9.3.5-2.pgdg14.10+1) ...
 * Stopping PostgreSQL 9.3 database server                                                                                                                                                                                     * Error: /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main is not accessible or does not exist
                                                                                                                                                                                                                       [fail]
invoke-rc.d: initscript postgresql, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing package postgresql-9.3 (--purge):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 postgresql-9.3
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
Failed to perform requested operation on package.  Trying to recover:
Setting up postgresql-common (166.pgdg14.10+1) ...
 * Starting PostgreSQL 9.3 database server                                                                                                                                                                                     * Error: /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main is not accessible or does not exist
                                                                                                                                                                                                                       [fail]
 * Starting PostgreSQL 9.4 database server                                                                                                                                                                                     * Error: /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main is not accessible or does not exist
                                                                                                                                                                                                                       [fail]
invoke-rc.d: initscript postgresql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package postgresql-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 postgresql-common

jj@testdev:/var/lib/postgresql$
```

**EDIT 3:**

Here are the results of running the command "sudo apt-get purge postgresql-client-9.4 postgresql-client-common postgresql-common"

```
Removing postgresql-common (166.pgdg14.10+1) ...
 * Stopping PostgreSQL 9.3 database server                                                                                                                                                                                     * Error: /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main is not accessible or does not exist
                                                                                                                                                                                                                       [fail]
 * Stopping PostgreSQL 9.4 database server                                                                                                                                                                                     * Error: /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main is not accessible or does not exist
                                                                                                                                                                                                                       [fail]
invoke-rc.d: initscript postgresql, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing package postgresql-common (--purge):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
 * Starting PostgreSQL 9.3 database server                                                                                                                                                                                     * Error: /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main is not accessible or does not exist
                                                                                                                                                                                                                       [fail]
 * Starting PostgreSQL 9.4 database server                                                                                                                                                                                     * Error: /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main is not accessible or does not exist
                                                                                                                                                                                                                       [fail]
invoke-rc.d: initscript postgresql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
```

and when I check what's installed:

```
jj@testdev:/var/lib/postgresql$ sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall | grep post
libreoffice-sdbc-postgresql         install
postgresql-9.3                  purge
postgresql-9.4                  purge
postgresql-common               purge
printer-driver-postscript-hp            install
jj@testdev:/var/lib/postgresql$
```

Comment: What happens when you try `sudo apt-get -f install`?

Comment: From the error message "Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages" so ... `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/48014/how-force-remove-when-post-installation-script-always-fail

Comment: @muru, the solution in that post does not work. I still get the same error as using apt-get remove.

Comment: Maybe try a simple reinstall? Aptitude might also help. Run `apt-get install aptitude` then run `aptitude purge [package name(s)]`. Aptitude just tries harder than apt-get to complete the requested operation.

Comment: @Zacharee1 re-install doesn't work either.  Please see Edit 2 re: details on aptitude results

Comment: All you did was try to purge it. The output is saying that the package isn't installed, so you should try installing it.

Comment: @Zacharee1 no, actually, I've been trying to re-install as well.  But as I mentioned in my earlier comment, the install fails with the same message.  I tried to install with aptitute as well via the command "sudo aptitude install postgresql-9.4"

Comment: this issue is actually preventing me from installing any packages on the machine.  All attempts fail with some flavor of the same message about postgresql-common

Comment: Did you try sudo apt-get purge postgresql*

Comment: @WeareBorg Yes, he did.

Comment: May I see the output of sudo apt-get purge postgresql* please. I cannot find it in the post or the answers below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the plethora of attempts to delete using `aptitude` and also `apt-get remove/purge`, I was getting a message that it couldn't delete `postgresql-9.3` because the directories `/var/lib/postgresql` and `/var/log/postgresql` were not empty.

So I blew them away and then did the `sudo apt-get purge`... which sort of worked.
And then I did `aptitude purge` and it worked.

Now I can install packages again on this box without errors.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to just purge the packages left from the failed removal attempt manually?

```
sudo apt-get purge postgresql-client-9.4 postgresql-client-common postgresql-common
```

Then:

```
sudo apt-get update install postgresql
```

The removal obviously fails because `postgresql` is not installed, but the reinstallation might be failing because something is wrong with what has been left from the previous installation.

Comment: kos, please see edit 3

Comment: after trying your suggestion, i also retried removing via aptitude toold.  what do you think of line 42 on this pastebin? http://pastebin.com/CjtmQDie

Comment: @dot I think I've got this: run `sudo gedit /var/lib/dpkg/info/postgresql-9.3.prerm` and comment (by adding a # at the start) this line: `. /usr/share/postgresql-common/maintscripts-functions`, then try purging again

Answer (score 0):

I had run into this problem by looking for all postgresql folders using `whereis postgresql` and then manually deleting them. But then when I needed to reinstall postgresql using `apt-get install postrgesql-10` or do a simple `apt-get upgrade`, I was getting the below as part of the error:

> Can't open /usr/share/postgresql-common/maintscripts-functions

What I did was that I copied the actual file from their Github repo [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbq/postgresql-common/master/debian/maintscripts-functions) and placed it at that location. Then I did the following steps:

- `dpkg -l | grep postgresql` - to list the packages that were installed. This will show you the result like [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZY9bE.png).
- Use the package names from the above result and remove them - `sudo apt-get remove <PACKAGE>`
- Next, remove all leftover packages with `sudo apt-get autoremove`

Restart your machine once after this and you should be good to go!

Answer (score 0):

This command will give you all the postgres packages installed .

```
sudo apt list --install | grep postgres
```

I also had the above mentioned problem but this command helped me to uninstall all the previous versions

```
sudo apt-get autoremove postgresql*
```