# Remove and reinstall mysql

Tags: mysql, uninstall, mariadb

I unfortunately messed up my mysql installation, when I thought I could just install mariadb next to it. Now I am not even able to remove and re-install it. As I have a lot of other things set up in this system I would like to avoid to freshly install Ubuntu.

So far I tried everything that was proposed in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/763623/379286) and also what is proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25244706/3562088). However I end up with the following error message:

[image: Error message in terminal]

What can I do to rescue the system. I don't care about the data in the sql database as this is gone for good now I believe.

When trying to `sudo dpkg --purge --force-all mysql-server` and `sudo apt install mysql-server` I get the error message:

```
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf doesn't exist
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dpendency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet. 

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configured): 
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport repport written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure. 
Errors were encountered while processing: 
mysql-server-5.8 
mysql-server 
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: So I'm seeing it mentions missing `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`.  That comes as part of `mysql-common` package.  Consider doing `apt-get remove --purge mysql-server` first then   try installing that `mysql-common` package , and finally reinstalling server and client package

Comment: Sorry for continuous editing on the comment. Kinda hard to type on mobile right now

Comment: Hi Sergiy, thanks for your comment. When I try doing `sudo apt-get remove --purge` it say `Setting up mysql-server-5.7` and then tells me `alternative path /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf` does not exist. It also says `my-sql-server-5.7 is not configured yet` and ends with `/usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Comment: OK, same error. And does `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server` or `mysql-server-5.7` return anything meaningful ?

Comment: If it keeps failing try https://askubuntu.com/a/369309/295286 Basically `sudo dpkg --purge --force-all mysql-server`

Comment: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server` returns `mysql-server is broken or not fully installed` and `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.7` returns `mysql-server-5.7 is broken or not fully installed` :/

Comment: Ok and after `sudo dpkg --purge --force-all mysql-server` can I just trying to re-install by `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`?

Comment: Alright, I'll touch base later. Perhaps someone can come along with a better idea, but so far that's all I've got.

Comment: Yes, try reinstalling now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82132/discussion-between-sergiy-kolodyazhnyy-and-axel).

Answer (score 1):

With user Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy's help I was able to detect that the problem was a process running in the background that was still blocking files. After killing that process and using `sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-\*` to remove every last bit of mysql on the system I freshly installed mysql.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you list what you have connected with mysql:

```
apt list --installed | grep mysql
```

It is just OK to purge mysql-common because w/o that package mysql will not work.

```
apt purge mysql-common
```

I tested on my end and it will also remove and purge this :

```
Purg mariadb-server [1:10.1.35+maria-1~bionic]
Purg mariadb-server-10.1 [1:10.1.35+maria-1~bionic]
Purg mariadb-client-10.1 [1:10.1.35+maria-1~bionic]
Purg percona-toolkit [3.0.6+dfsg-2]
Purg libdbd-mysql-perl [4.046-1]
Purg mariadb-server-core-10.1 [1:10.1.35+maria-1~bionic]
Purg mariadb-client-core-10.1 [1:10.1.35+maria-1~bionic]
Purg libmariadbclient18 [1:10.1.35+maria-1~bionic] [libmysqlclient18:amd64 ]
Purg libmysqlclient18 [1:10.1.35+maria-1~bionic]
Purg libmysqlclient20 [5.7.23-0ubuntu0.18.04.1]
Purg mariadb-common [1:10.1.35+maria-1~bionic]
Purg mysql-common [1:10.1.35+maria-1~bionic]
```